# Symfony 1 - admin generator values from embed form

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, propel

```
JobeetCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    test: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

JobeetJob:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
    type:         { type: string(255) }
    company:      { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  relations:
    JobeetCategory: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: JobeetJobs }
```

In JobeetJobForm i added:

```
$cat = new JobeetCategory();
$this->embedForm('category', $cat);
```

and i generated ADMIN.

Now i can all widgets from these forms. I can change this in generator.yml. There is position **form**

```
  form:
    display:
      One: [category_id, type]
      Two:   [company, test] // test - not working
```

i have error widget test not exists. How can i use embed form in generator?

i try:

```
  form:
    display:
      One: [category_id, type]
      Two:   [company, JobeetCategory[test]]
```

but this also not working.

Comment: What is `test` in your case? A company name?

Comment: This is additional field in JobetCategory

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a lonely field from an embed form, you should add the whole embed form to the display key.

```
  form:
    display:
      One: [category_id, type]
      Two: [company, category]
```

Comment: i know this, but how can i add for this field test?

Comment: The test field is inside the embed category form, so if you display the embed category form, you will display the test field as well as the name field.